# Using bitcoin trezor's ssh agent

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, hardware-wallet, trezor

I'm trying to use hardware wallet [trezor.io](http://trezor.io) as login agent for ssh protocol, which is quite cool idea.

According their how-to

http://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-apps/sshagent.html

I'm trying to proceed with instalation:

```
$ sudo pip install trezor_agent
```

but it fails with:

```
hidapi/libusb/hid.c:47:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
#include <libusb.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
                        ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ihidapi/hidapi -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c hidapi/libusb/hid.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hidapi/libusb/hid.o

hidapi/libusb/hid.c:47:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory

 #include <libusb.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...

    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm using ubuntu 14 lts and have no experience with python. I removed most of compilation log

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear.

> libusb.h: No such file or directory

The package have a dependecy that pip can solve. You need to install libusb first.

```
apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Every time you get such message **no such file or directory** you can check what you need to install with

```
dpkg -S 'missing_file"
```

or

```
apt-file list "missing_file"
```